# MongoDB Java driver: distinct with sort

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, distinct

Using the MongoDB console I can write a native MongoDB query using distinct key with a sort like this:

```
db.mycollection.distinct('mykey').sort('mykey', 1)
```

Using the Java driver I would expect to be able to write the same query like this:

```
myCollection.distinct("myKey").sort(new BasicDBObject("myKey", 1));
```

However, this doesn't work because `DBCollection#distinct()` returns type `List` and not type `DBCursor` like `DBCollection#find()`.

How can I write the distinct query with a sort using the Java driver?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support server-side sorting with the `distinct` command.  What's happening in the console is that the `distinct('myKey')` call returns an array and then you're calling the JavaScript `sort` method on that array which returns a sorted version of the array.  The parameters you pass into `sort` are ignored.

To do the equivalent in Java you would do:

```
List myKeys = myCollection.distinct("myKey");
java.util.Collections.sort(myKeys);
```

To get the unique keys using a server-side sort you could use `aggregate`.  Here's how you'd do that in the shell:

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { $group: {_id: '$myKey' }},
    { $sort: {_id: 1}}
])
```

However, when I tested this, the simple client-side sort approach performed much better.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I guess sorting on the client side is fine unless pagination is needed for a large set of results. (will come back and submit the bounty later).

Answer (score -1):

You can actually use pure javascript

```
db.mycollection.distinct('mykey').sort()
```

or pass a compare function for more elaborated sorting:

```
db.users.distinct('mykey').sort(function(a, b){return a >b})
```

*Tested on robomongo*