# Distinct in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, distinct

How to get distinct from a collection basis of id in mongodb using java code.

please suggest me the java code to get the distinct.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18478924/2177138

Answer (score 2):

First get the connection

```
    mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    chatsDB = mongoClient.getDatabase("productfeeds");
    docCollection = chatsDB.getCollection("products");
```

then use this query;

```
ArrayList<String> prodRetailer = docCollection.distinct("merchant_name", String.class)
                                .filter(new Document("merchant_name"))
                                .into(new ArrayList<String>());
```

you get the distinct list

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregation pipeline for this:

```
db.foo.aggregate({_id: "$myDistinctField"})
```